# How can i use MBProgressHUD in multiple ViewControllers?

Tags: objective-c

I have a problem using the MBProgressHUD library. I can use it normally in my main ViewController, but, then, when i try to import the .h file in other view controller, i have the following error:

> Redefinition of enumerator 'MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate'
>
> Redefinition of enumerator 'MBProgressHUDModeDeterminate'
>   ...

Does anyone knows how can i manage it?

Thanks

EDIT: I have the following imports in my main view controller

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "FMDatabase.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"

@implementation ViewController
```

When i try to put this imports in other view controller, i get the errors:

```
#import "FinalViewController.h"
#import "Parse/Parse.h"
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"

@implementation FinalViewController
```

I have used the MBProgressHUD library from this link https://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD

Comment: Is `FinalViewController` a subclass of `ViewController`?

Comment: Yes

@interface FinalViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>

Answer (score 0):

You're probably `#include`-ing `MBProgressHUD.h` rather that `#import`-ing it. `#import` ensures that it's only imported once.

Comment: I'm importing (#import) it at the start of my viewController .m, where i want to use the library

Comment: Ok, that sounds right. Can you show the `#import`s that are in the `.h` and `.m` files of the relevant view controllers please?

Answer (score 0):

I've used MBProgressHUD exclusively in my apps, and across multiple view controllers and never seen that issue before.

You could try and add your import statement to your .pch file rather than import for each view controller. It will add the header even if you don't use it, but might be worth a go.

Also, make sure you only have one copy of the header file in your project. The error you are showing almost looks like it is being defined twice which would indicate too many headers.

Comment: I've tried to add the import in the pch file, and i get the same error. 

I only have one copy of the header file. If i use the library in only one view controller, it works fine. The problem starts when I import the library in other view controller. I cant understand it

Comment: I think I've found the problem. The Parse library also have an implementation of the MBProgressHUD library, so it returns me the error. 

Thanks for all for helping me with this problem :)